# How to display variable sized items?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a list of strings that I want them to be clickable and to be displayed horizontally next to each other, if there is no space left, container should continue to arrange items in the next line. Please help me.
[image: as you can see, I have failed to do this using GridView]

Comment: You need to share the markup where you're generating these. Then only, someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Put some Buttons in a WrapPanel...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Items in ItemsControl takes width of First Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695139/items-in-itemscontrol-takes-width-of-first-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a WrapPanel to get that kind of layout. It is not available in  Windows Runtime standard controls, [here](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/02/20/Creating-a-WrapPanel-for-your-Windows-Runtime-apps.aspx) you can find an implementation for it.

Usage:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemControl.Items>
       <!-- put your strings here or use ItemTemplate instead -->
    </ItemControl.Items>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: No this has a problem = the WrapPanel is only available in WPF not in UWP

Comment: @HesamKashefi Did you even read my answer? I provided a link to an implementation of WrapPanel.

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't know why I just saw the code! Thank you so much !

Comment: WrapPanel can use in uwp